# The sentinel value isn't working and the program runs too early

Tags: python, python-3.x

So when I put in the values that I was given the program stops before it is supposed to which is at 123 as opposed to -1. I did replace{while grade_entered >=0 and grade_entered <= 100:} with {while grade_entered != '-1':} ,a sentinel value, but the program doesn't run if I do that. I also added continue as I thought it keeps the program running if I enter a number that isn't In the 0 - 100 range but that didn't help at all. My question is where am I supposed to add the sentinel value{while grade_entered != '-1':} in order for the program to end after I insert -1?

<You need to count how many passing grades are entered. Use a sentinel-controlled while loop that will ask the user to enter student grades until a value of -1 is entered.  Use a counter variable to count all the grades that are passing grades, where 50 is the minimum passing grade. If there are any grades that are out of the valid range (0 through 100), present an error message to the user, and do not count that grade as passing (or valid). We also would like to see what percentage of the valid grades are passing.>

```
# 1st Test Case
# 45
# 90
# 70
# 87
# 123      That is not a valid test grade!
# 100      You have entered 4 passing grades.
# -1       80.0% of the valid grades are passing.

count = 0
total = 0
grade_entered = 0
print('Enter test scores to average. Enter -1 to Quit:')

while grade_entered >= 0 and grade_entered <= 100:
    grade_entered = float(input(""))
    if grade_entered >= 0 and grade_entered <= 100:
        total += grade_entered
        count += 1
        continue
else:
    print('This is not a valid grade!')

print("You have entered " + str(count) + " passing grades.")
average = total / count
print("{:.2f}% of the valid grades are passing".format(average))
```

This is the result that I get

```
Enter test scores to average. Enter -1 to Quit:
45
90
70
87
123
This is not a valid grade!
You have entered 4 passing grades.
73.00% of the valid grades are passing
```

Comment: *"I did replace ... with {while grade_entered != '-1':} ,a sentinel value, but the program doesn't run if I do that."* - Did you try checking against `-1` (an int) or `-1.0` (a float) instead of `'-1'` (a string)?

Comment: I am so dumb I don't know why I didn't realize to not try it as a string. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is important to do correct indentations when using python, your else clause is not part of the while loop anymore because it is too far left.

The whole thing should look somewhat like this:

```
grade_entered = float(input(""))
while grade_entered != -1:
    if grade_entered >= 0 and grade_entered <= 100:
        total += grade_entered
        count += 1
        #continue this is unnecesarry
    else:
        print('This is not a valid grade!')
    grade_entered = float(input(""))
```

Comment: I read the comment above but yeah I shouldn't have put <'-1':> instead of just <-1:> I should have looked at that more closely. But still thank you for the help.